# Image not rendering

Tags: css, reactjs

I have this code that doesn't render the image.

```
import styled from 'styled-components';
import ImageDiv from '../../shared/Image-div';
import { sideimage, signin } from '../../../assets/images';
import device from '../../../config/device';

const LogoDiv = styled(ImageDiv)`
  background-image: url(${signin});
  @media ${device.mobileS} {
    background-image: url(${sideimage});
  }
`;
export default LogoDiv;
```

Rendered code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { sideimage } from '../../../assets/images';
import SignUpButton from './sign-up-button';
import Input from '../../shared/Input-field';
import LogoDiv from '../../shared/Image-div';
import FormDiv from '../../shared/Sign-in-div';
import { NunitoItalic18, Nunito20 } from '../../shared/nunito/nunito';
import ImageContainer from '../../shared/image-container';
import ScreenDiv from '../../shared/screen-div';

type Props = {
  setDisplayScreen: Function,
};

const marginInputPercentage = '4.3%';
const marginTopPercentage = '12.3%';
const buttonMarginPercentage = '6.7%';

const SignIn = ({ setDisplayScreen }: Props) => (
  <ScreenDiv>
    <ImageContainer>
      <LogoDiv />
    </ImageContainer>

);

export default SignIn;
```

This is the code base being used for the assignment.

Code for `assets/images`

```
import logo from './qiisologo/qiiso.png'; 
import signup from './signup/signup.png'; 
import signin from './signin/signin.jpg'; 
import sideimage from './signin/sideimage.jpg'; 

export { logo, signup, signin, sideimage };
```

Am I using a wrong syntax, because the image doesn't render? Thank you.

Comment: what is { sideimage } is that the url or the image? how is your assets folder structured?

Comment: assets folder is working because if I go to the original ImageDiv and put the url there it works, meaning a copy of imagediv and trying to overwrite the logo is the problem

Comment: `'../../../assets/images'` this is a js file? If yes, can you add the code?

Comment: Can you do this and see if the text is rendered? `<LogoDiv>Image here</LogoDiv> `